# Can we configure WSO2 Identity Servers 6.0.0 as Key Manager on WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

1. We are planning to upgrade

   `WSO2 IS 5.10.0 to  6.0.0`

   `WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 to 4.1.0`
2. As part of Configure WSO2 IS as a Key Manager

   `What is the Compatible WSO2 Identity Servers version (as Key Manager)?? for WSO2 APIM 4.1.0`
3. `Can we configure WSO2 Identity Servers 6.0.0 as Key Manager on WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0??`
4. As part of WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0, suggested to user WSO IS 5.11.0 as Key Manager can we use WSO2 IS 6.0.0?
   https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/#step-1-configure-wso2-is

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server 6.0.0 is not compatible with APIM 4.1 and according to the official docs, only WSO2 Identity Server 5.11 and WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0 are tested with, WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0. Refer to [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/) for more information. So IMO, it's better if you move forward with 5.11.0.

Comment: Yes as per official  docs, APIM 4.1.0 tested on WSO2 IS 5.11 and WSO2 EI 6.6.0
**Any new release of APIM to support WSO2 IS 6.0.0?**
**How do i use that latest version of WSO2 APIM with WSO2 IS 6.0.0 as Key manager?**

As per official docs, From API Manager 3.2.0 onwards, WSO2 Identity Server is not packaged as a Key Manager. A remote WSO2 Identity Server instance should be used as the Key Manager. 
**What is remote WSO2 Identity Server instance here?
Can we install WSO2 IS 6.0.0 as remote instance and configure as a key manager?**

Comment: The remote IS instance here is IS 5.11. Please refer the doc - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/

If there are API changes in IS 6.0.0, it won't work as in IS 5.11.0.