# WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager - Is the WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 compatible with the WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to setup WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0 as the Key Manager for WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0.
Is the WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 compatible with the WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From APIM 3.2 you can connect any IS version as an External Key Manager. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0 is not compatible with WSO2 API Manager  4.1.0 according to the official docs[1]. WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0  is tested with, WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0.  Refer to this[2] for more information.

But WSO2 Identity Server 6.0.0 & 6.1.0 is compatible with latest APIM 4.2.0 product[3]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/#tested-wso2-products

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020320/10055162

[3] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/#tested-wso2-products